# looking for a way to apply collapsible feature to headings in word document using open xml

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, ms-word, openxml

I am trying to render the heading part when i am generating the word document programmatically using the below code

```
    private static Paragraph BuildSubHeaderPart(string headingText)
    {
        Paragraph headerParagraph = new Paragraph();

        var runProperty = new RunProperties();

        runProperty.Append(new RunFonts() { Ascii = "Nirmala UI", HighAnsi = "Nirmala UI" }
            , new FontSize { Val = new StringValue("22") }
            , new Bold()
            , new Color() { Val = "55B6DA" });
        runProperty.Append(new Text(headingText) { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Default });
        headerParagraph.AppendChild(new Run()).Append(runProperty);

        return headerParagraph;
    }
```

Appending the heading to body like as below

```
  var mainDocumentPart = wordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
  Document doc = new Document();
  mainDocumentPart.Document = doc;
  doc.Body = new Body();

  Body body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
  body.AppendChild(BuildSubHeaderPart("MECHANICAL SYSTEMS"));
```

and this is working fine, Now i am looking way to apply `collapsible/Expand` feature to this heading using  the c# code that will looks like as below image

[image]

Is there any way i can achieve this feature, I am using Open XML with .Net Core to generate the word document.

Could any one suggest any idea on this one, Many thanks in advance.

Updated Code :

```
  Paragraph headerParagraph = new Paragraph();
        ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
        OpenXmlUnknownElement openXmlUnknownElement1 = OpenXmlUnknownElement.CreateOpenXmlUnknownElement("<w15:collapsed xmlns:w15=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml\" />");
        paragraphProperties1.Append(openXmlUnknownElement1);
        var runProperty = new RunProperties();
        runProperty.Append(new RunFonts() { Ascii = "Nirmala UI", HighAnsi = "Nirmala UI" }
            , new FontSize { Val = new StringValue("22") }
            , new Bold()
            , new Color() { Val = "55B6DA" });
        runProperty.Append(new Text(headingText) { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Default });
        headerParagraph.Append(paragraphProperties1);
        headerParagraph.AppendChild(new Run()).Append(runProperty);
```

Comment: Could any one please let me know how can we add expand/collapse features to heading using open xml Or please let me know if this all not make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this for a Paragraph, but if you want all paragraphs of a *Style* to be collapsed you will need to use similar code to modify the Style.

```
ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();


// having the level makes it collapsible
// You'll need to change the level as appropriate in { Val = 1 }
// so either you'll need to pass an outline level parameter to your
// method and set the level (or no level) 
//or perhaps have a second method to add these outline level paras.
OutlineLevel outlineLevel1 = new OutlineLevel() { Val = 1 };


//Having the w15:collapsed element makes the show as
// collapsed when you open the document.
// if you want it expanded on open, do not add
// this element
OpenXmlUnknownElement openXmlUnknownElement1 = OpenXmlUnknownElement.CreateOpenXmlUnknownElement("<w15:collapsed xmlns:w15=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml\" />");
paragraphProperties1.Append(outlineLevel1);
paragraphProperties1.Append(openXmlUnknownElement1);
headerParagraph.Append(paragraphProperties);
```

If you haven't encountered the Office Open XML Productivity Tool, you may find it useful: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425

[BTW, I think what you are describing here is a *Heading*. In Word, a *Header* is the area at the top of a page (with a *Footer* at the bottom)]

Comment: thanks for the input, how can i apply this for already existing heading .. could you please point me in the right direction .. i have my code put in a `BuildSubHeaderPart` and I would like add collapsible feature for the heading that is using this function ..

Comment: I updated my code and it is not working and i am not able to see the small triangle near to the heading .. could you please suggest any ideas

Comment: I will leave my first question and then looking to throw a bounty on this

Comment: thanks .. i have added my updated code as well but still it is not working..

Comment: many thanks for updating those, i have a small problem here when i tried to open the generated document the heading are all collapsed but not expanded .. I would like to expand all the headers when i open the document.

Comment: yeah thanks for the correction and many thanks for the support ..

Comment: I added only outline and it is working with outline though i need to apply this to each individual heading not in the common function

Comment: sorry i have one more question regarding this, i  have main heading where i need to be able to collapse entire document by clicking on this so is there any change in the above code